# VBA If statement condition evalutes to False, but it runs as if it is True in Worksheet SelectionChange Event

Tags: excel, vba

In short my code in SelectionChange event is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Right(Target.Cells(1, 1).Value, 4) = ".txt" And DataSize < 30000 Then
            Me.Shapes("txtFileBox").TextFrame.Characters.Text = ReadTextFile(Target.Cells(1, 1).Value)
        End If
        
End Sub
```

An error is raised perhaps because of loading too large text into TextBox. Public DataSize (long type) variable is checked to avoid loading big text into TextBox shape on the worksheet, and this check works fine in condition statement.

The problem is that even though condition in If statement is evaluated to False (detected on Watches window), the statement within If statement is still executed.

What is the cause of this problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Where do you populate `DataSize`? And how did you evaluate the if condition in the watch window?

Comment: Is there a `On Error Resume Next` somewhere?

Comment: @Storax DataSize is Module level variable, and it is set in Public Sub ReadTextFile in that Module. When the Even is run for large text file, a run-time error 1004 stops the program and I drag and drops the condition expression in Watches window, which shows False because of DataSize is bigger than 30000.

Comment: @Stringeater No, there is no Resume Next..

Comment: So you checked `Right(Target.Cells(1, 1).Value, 4) = ".txt" And DataSize < 30000` in the watch window? Did you also check the single values of `DataSize` and  `Right(Target.Cells(1, 1).Value, 4)` in the watch window? PS The code resp. the if condition works fine for me.

Comment: @Storax yes, Right(...) is evaluated True, bu DataSize < 30000 evaluated False, so the combined is False. I even checked the DataSize value by hovering mouse over the variable in VBE.

Comment: Does DataSize raise a SelectionChange event? Could it be that Worksheet_SelectionChange runs twice? You can check this with a static Long variable that you increment each time.

Comment: Ok, then I am out of ideas. Sorry!

Comment: Try adding `Application.EnableEvents = False` to the top of your procedure and `Application.EnableEvents = True` to the end.

Comment: @Stringeater Runs twice?, no, a list of text files pathes in a selected folder is populated on the worksheet, and when user goes down or up on (selection change) the list, "ReadTextFile" Function reads the text file selected and set DataSize variable, and returns text data. IS IT that DataSize must be set with another Function other than the one inside IF statement??? it might be the Cause??

Comment: Can you also tell us the full error code and description, please.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry Run time error 1004, Unable to set Text property of the Characters class

Comment: Put a break point at the top of your procedure, then step through your code using F8 to see the exact line that causes the error. Can you add the code for the `DataSize` declaration and the `ReadTextFile`? It is very difficult to make suggestions without examining the rest of your code.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry I managed to solve the problem with adding this line before IF statement: Debug.Print ReadTextFile(Target.Cells(1, 1).Value) .   Since DataSize is set inside ReadTextFile function, it is always zero before IF statement. DataSize must be set before IF statement. However I should find a better way to get DataSize. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

with all guidance and help above, I managed to solve the problem with editing the code into:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim TextData As Variant
    If Right(Target.Cells(1, 1).Value, 4) = ".txt" Then
        TextData = ReadTextFile(Target.Cells(1, 1).Value)  '' Function ReadTextFile should be run before If Statemet
    End If
    '' if DataSize is in reasonable size
    If DataSize < 30000 Then  '' DataSize is a module level variable set by ReadTextFile function when reading text file
        Me.Shapes("txtFileBox").TextFrame.Characters.Text = TextData
    End If
    
End Sub
```